# Dynamically importing a user-specified excel file into AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I would like to create an AnyLogic model that is capable of allowing a user to select a specific excel file, upon which the model will run. The file that the user selects will be the input data for the model. This must be done by allowing the user input to come via the simulation experimental screen (the experimental screen).

I only have the personal learning version (free) of Anylogic, and not the professional (paid) version. Therefore, this must be possible with the free version.

I would really appreciate any help :)
Thanks.

I have tried using a control button whereby the entry can be the file path. I then link that to a variable. But I haven't been successful with this so far.

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Welcome again, happy to help

Comment: check this out: 
https://noorjax.com/2018/11/19/using-file-chooser-in-ple/